# Display different image on hover with transition

Tags: html, css

On the image `hover`, I want to display a different small image on it with a `background` and `opacity` so that the original image is still visible. I want to use the `transition` to slow the hover effect.
So here's what I'm trying and not working:

**HTML:**

```
<img src="http://i50.tinypic.com/2poy3kl.jpg" class="test" />
```

**CSS:**

```
.test {
   background: red url("http://i50.tinypic.com/10mue4k.png");
   transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
}

.test:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;   
}
```

**JS Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/AXQW4/2/

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need an additional wrapper for this. Exactly the size of the image, and give that the background. Then, when you hover over the image, you hide it and the underlying background is revealed.

**[Live example](http://dabblet.com/gist/3787392)**

### HTML

```
<div class="background">
    <img src="http://i50.tinypic.com/2poy3kl.jpg">
</div>
```

### CSS

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.background {
    background: url("http://i50.tinypic.com/10mue4k.png");
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
}
.background img {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
}
.background img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

No need to know the exact dimensions of the image.

Answer (score 3):

Is this something you were looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/AXQW4/3/

Answer (score 2):

One more demo :)

http://jsfiddle.net/AXQW4/7/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want  **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ohuhos/3/edit)**
Or this **[LINK](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/)**

```
.test {
   background: red url("http://i50.tinypic.com/10mue4k.png");

 -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.test:hover {
  opacity:.5;
}
```